# Can't install PHP

Tags: windows-10, installation, php

I'm trying to install PHP on my Windows 10 64 bit computer.

I downloaded php 7.0.4 Win32 from http://windows.php.net/download/ and extracted the contents to a local directory.

I try to run php-win.exe and other than the wait cursor showing for less than 1/2 a second, nothing happens.

I then tried to run php.exe and I get a console window.

Event viewer shows nothing.

How do I find out why this application is not executing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately thats not how PHP works.

PHP is an interpereter which reads and executes scripted code files (.php or similarr files).  To write/test/develop in PHP - all you really need is notepad.

Once you've written your scripts and are ready to test, you don't actually install PHP as much as extract is, configure it and then run it through IIS

Look at the installation guide at:
http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php to see how to install, run and configure PHP.

Essentially, you need to:

- Install the VC14 X64 runtime (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=48145)
- Extract PHP zip file to a directory (C:\PHP or similar)
- Enable the IIS Web Server Role and ensure that you include the CGI module as part of this.
- Create a new FastCGI module in IIS pointing to the php.exe file
- Make any changes required to your php ini file
- Add your website files or application files to a web browser
- run your application via command line (`"C:\php\php.exe" script.php`) or by opening a web browser and pointing to `http://localhost/wherever/your/application/is.php`

If you get stuck on any of these stages specifically, ask away and I will do my best to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the WAMP package. ( http://www.wampserver.com/en/ )
You will have all the necessary software to start learning PHP with a simple "click Next" installer.

After installing, create a folder inside the C:\wamp\www folder and write your php pages in it. ( C:\wamp64\www if you're running the 64 bit version)

To see the output of the pages access http://localhost/nameofyourfolder in the browser. It will search for the file index.php and display the processed output.